# Change a Solidworks Drawing Overridden DImension

Tags: vb.net, solidworks

I have a program in VB.Net that changes Part/Assembly dimensions in Solidworks. There is a *drawing* dimension titled "**RD3@Transport**" which I have chosen to Override by clicking the "Override Value:" checkbox in Solidworks at setting its Override Value to 10, just as a starting point. I then have the following code, which has the puprose of changing this value to, in this example, 12.625:

```
    Sub D_PointToSeam()
        swDim = swModel.Parameter("RD3@Transport")
        swDim.SetValue3(12.625, swSetValueInConfiguration_e.swSetValue_InThisConfiguration, Nothing)
        swModel.EditRebuild3()
      End Sub
```

where swModel is properly defined and initialized. This code runs with no exception, but when I view the Drawing, I still see the Overridden value I initially defined (10) , not the one I want with my code (12.625).

Am I doing this wrong, or is there another way to accomplish my goal?